# How to add additional IP's to SPF record along with Google Apps SPF

Tags: spf

My current SPF record looks like:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

I'm trying to add some extra IP's to this record (for our shipping system, that emails out form our domain). The issue is that currently they are getting marked as spam with a "soft fail" (due to the IP's not matching Google's). I found this post about adding multiple IP's to the records:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/add-two-ip-addresses-to-an-spf-record

However, I'm not sure how I would edit my above SPD record to achieve this. Is it as simple as just doing:

```
v=spf1 +a +mx ip4:167.XX.XXX.247 ip4:167.XX.XXX.40  include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

(I don't want to do this wrong, as it'll break all our current mailing systems - thus asking the question :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's as simple as that.

But if it's only the two IP's you want to add, you should not add the `+a` and `+mx`, since this will just add additional un-needed DNS lookups for the resolving mail-server.

Comment: thanks - its actually 4 extra IP's I want to add (along with the google apps), so that would be ok to add 4 x `ip4:xxxx` settings along with the `include:`  bit?

Comment: yes, you can add as many `ip4:xxxx` as you want/need (within the limit of the DNS record length), since these entries don't add additional DNS lookups.